# python - Change one-row table value

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas

I'm developing a script for a tables. I had a problem, that the table came with decimal values ​​and I'm trying to make a change of these values ​​in the code.

To do that, just take the decimal value and multiply it by 1000, but there's a problem that I really can't understand. It works up to a certain number, then the values ​​of some
rows of the table change and the result at the end is of immense value. I don't know what's going on, someone can give me a hand.

Put the entire code of the function

```
def DESTINOS_CLUBE_CLIENTE_MOD072():
    # Caminho do arquivo xlsx  # Sheet_name Nome da tabela ou planilha. Obs: Tem que ser EXATAMENTE como está escrito no excel.
    table = pd.read_excel('./planilha.xlsx', sheet_name='LP')
    oneCard = ""

    # Remoção de linhas que não contém valores   
    for i in range(table.shape[0]):
        if pd.isna(table[1][i]) == True:
            table = table.drop(labels=i, axis=0) 
    
    table.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    
    # Criar nova tabela
    table2 = pd.DataFrame(table)
    # Resetar o index da nova tabela
    table2.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

    for i in range(8):
        print(table2[1][i])
        valor2 = int(table2[1][i] * 1000)
        table2[1] = table2[1].replace(table2[1][i], valor2)
        print("------")


    # table2 = table2.astype({1 : 'int32'})
    # table2 = table2.astype({'1.1': 'int32'})
    print(table2)
    
    # Pegando os valores da tabela e inserindo em seus determinados campos 
    for i in range(table2.shape[0]):
        values = 'element{}.querySelector("{}").value="{}"; element{}.querySelector("{}").value="{}"; element{}.querySelector("{}").value="{}"; element{}.querySelector("{}").value="{}"; element{}.querySelector("{}").value="{}";' . format(i, "input[name*='Origem']", table2['ORIGEM'][i], i, "input[name*='Destino']", table2['DESTINOS'][i], i, "input[name*='Clube_valor']", table2[1][i], i, "input[name*='Geral_valor']", table2['1.1'][i], i, "input[name*='Link_botao']", table2['LINKS'][i])
        oneCard += " let element"+str(i)+" = document.querySelectorAll('[data-fieldname=Itens]')"+str([i])+"; setTimeout(()=>{"+values+"},10000);"

    # Código completo
    cod = "let totalElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-fieldname=Itens]').length == "+str(table2.shape[0])+" ? 0 : "+str(table2.shape[0])+" - document.querySelectorAll('[data-fieldname=Itens]').length; let element = document.querySelector('[data-fieldname=Itens]'); for(i = 0; i < totalElements; i++){element.children[13].click()} setTimeout(() => {"+oneCard+"}, 10000); setTimeout(() => {console.log('Pronto, pode publicar!')}, 20050);"

    # Inserir o código dentro de um arquivo de texto
    file(cod)
    # Mensagem de sucesso
    message()

DESTINOS_CLUBE_CLIENTE_MOD072()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you show how your data looks like?

Comment: ready, i changed man

Answer (score 1):

the problem was that I was just passing the value, so it got all the equal values ​​from the table. So I used `loc`, to select the line

```
for i in range(table2.shape[0]):
        valor2 = int(table2[1][i] * 1000)
        table2.loc[i] = table2.loc[i].replace(table2.loc[i][1], valor2)
```